# Fresh Magento 2.3.0 installation no CSS

Tags: php, css, magento, cpanel

Just installed Magento 2 on a shared server, everything seemed successful, no errors, but the shop looks like this (css files not found, they return 403 Forbidden, but the files are actually missing):

[image]

**It seems like the static content/css is not generated.**

pub/static:
[image]

The only file in pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/locale is **requirejs-config.js**, but there were supposed to also be other files, such as those CSS files:
[image]

I tried reinstalling it, changing folder permissions, different PHP version, nothing worked. It's strange that some folders are generated (also the requirejs file), but not the CSS.

How can I make sure the CSS is generated (without shell access) ?

Why would Magento clearly say installation was successful if it couldn't generate the static files? Can I somehow manually copy those static files?

**Specs:**

- PHP Version 7.1
- Magento CE 2.3.0
- Installed on a shared server, only have cPanel access, no shell

Comment: As you can't use shell, you should go to admin, the in menu, "Manage Cache" and clear (cache + magento 2). Would be easier if you had access to shell

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command and cache:flush.
**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**

Comment: Look in specs, "no shell" so not possible :/

Comment: Enable shell is best recommended.

Reference : https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ssh/enable/

Answer (score -1):

it's a very strange issue appears only in 2.3 version.
You should insert this SQL code in your project database ( or in PHPMyAdmin ui):

**insert core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);**